# Handle multiple http request HttpListener using multithread leads to strange behavior

Tags: c#, multithreading, httprequest, httplistener

i'm trying to create a `HttpListener` and accept Http request, for each `HttpListenerContext` i create a dedicated thread to do work on it like this

```
while(true)
{
    var context = listener.GetContext();
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() => HandleContext(context));
    backgroundThread.Start();
}
```

In the `HandleContext` i do a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` to simulate the work and `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)` for debugging purpose.
But when i open 3 tabs in Chrome at the same time, only 2 tabs return but the result is duplicated and the last tab just keep hanging.
[image]

As far as i know, my threads has no shared data which could lead to deadlock, but this behavior seems like a deadlock, can you tell me what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Here's my full code

```
class Program
    {
        private static HttpListener _listener;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:5001/");
            listener.Start();

            Listen(listener);
        }

        static void Listen(HttpListener listener)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var context = listener.GetContext();
                Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(() => HandleContext(context));
                backgroundThread.Start();
            }
        }

        static void HandleContext(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine($"Hello world, {DateTime.Now}");

            var responseContent = "Hello world";

            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseContent);

            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
            context.Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have an 'orphan' `listener.GetContext();` at the beginning of `static void Listen(HttpListener listener)` method. This context will not be processed, and this explains your tab 'empty'.

Comment: @Madhatter can you be more specific, the context is passed in the backgroundThread and the thread is start in the same scope of Context, then why is it "orphan"?

Comment: On the code you posted there is two `listener.GetContext();`. The first one is never sent to `HandleContext` method

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's not what i intended to do. But the Console.WriteLine is still being duplicated

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the `ContentLength64` property of your `HttpListenerResponse` stream !
Please try this

```
context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.LongLength;
using (Stream stream = context.Response.OutputStream)
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a while, i figured out that the "deadlock" like behavior occurred because of the "orphan" `GetContext` which @Mat Hatter pointed out. And the Console.WriteLine being duplicated because of Google Chrome's behavior sending 2 requests, 1 for the website's content and 1 for the fav.icon. Hence, there's nothing wrong with the Console.WriteLine being duplicated.